# Does a 1-Lipschitz function preserve mutual information between two random variables?

Tags: it.information-theory, information-geometry

Suppose we have a 1-Lipschitz function $f$ such that 1-Lipschitzness is preserved, with $D_A(f(X), f(Y)) \leq D_B(X, Y)$ for some metric spaces $A$ and $B$.

Does this also imply that $I(f(X); f(Y)) = I(X;Y)$? It seems intuitive that this would be the case if the 1-lipschitz function is injective, but I don't know if this is true, so that the mutual information is preserved under such invertible transformation. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: For discrete random variables this follows readily from the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-independent $A$-valued random variables, and let $f:A\to B$ be a constant function.  Then $I(f(X);f(Y))=0<I(X;Y)$.

Comment: Note the OP assumed $f$ is injective

Comment: Whoops! Thank you and sorry.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer: I don't know if $f$ is injective or not, but from @e.lipnowski comments it seems that $f$ isn't injective even if it's 1-Lipschitz, in which case I should suppose the MI is not preserved?